# Hellowired Theme checkout process not working on Magento CE 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

Magento Hellowired Theme checkout process not working on CE 1.8 but it works fine in CE 1.7

I'm having an issue with checkout process as on step 3 Shipping Method .

And also "Your Checkout Process" on the right bar doesn't get message.

Comment: I would suggest that the first thing you should do is contact the provided. But if they do not provide help then maybe knowing what exactly is not working would help us out.

Answer (score 7):

The checkout progress section has changed in 1.8.

> Improving the overall checkout process performance by loading the
>   progress information for the current checkout step only

You can check this in the [release notes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes) in the *Performance Improvements* section.

I'm almost sure that this is the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: This was the answer that led me to compare my theme's checkout.xml to the 1.8 checkout.xml. I just had to update my theme to use the 1.8 version...

Answer (score 3):

I have simmilar problem for payment method not worked in checkout page.upto shipping method is worked but not goes to payment method because of in checkout layout file for magento 1.8 some changes are done.

You have to find `template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml"` from `hellowired/layout/chekcout.xml` and replace `methods.phtml` file to `info.phtml` file.
so new template file path is like `template="checkout/onepage/payment/info.phtml"`
now working with magento 1.8 version.
its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Marius with checkout changing with 1.8.  I also think you will need to wait for the theme authors to release a new version compatible with Magento CE 1.8 at is is only compatible with Magento up to 1.7

Answer (score 0):

For me that makes it work.Try it if you like:

```
“/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtm”
```

**Change from that:**

```
<fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

**To that:**

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The changes are basically in checkout.xml and onepage.phtml files. Also if the custom theme has a js/opcheckout.js file, remove it.
You may also have to remove template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml and shipping.phtml files too.-

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue was in my checkout.xml layout file in my custom theme.

If you compare the checkout.xml in the base theme versus the one in your custom theme, you'll notice some major differences in the checkout progress blocks.