# Calculate shipping charges

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping

The module does not calculate shipping charges if there is only one piece product in the shopping cart.
I have only one rule basket. If the total is 100,000 HUF, I did not count shipping charges.

What could be the solution?

Update:
This was also a problem:

[Hellowired Theme checkout process not working on Magento CE 1.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9147/hellowired-theme-checkout-process-not-working-on-magento-ce-1-8)

I did this:

....?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods')...
To that:

..fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
        getChildHtml('methods')...

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: The shipping weight was incorrectly saved.
1 processor weight (product + packaging): approx. 0.5 kg.
The shipping weight started to 1 kg in the tablerates.csv.

Comment: Please accept your answer and it will close out the thread